# Trying to order rows by timestamps from two different tables Snowflake

Tags: join, datatable, timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-order-by

I have two tables as follows

TABLE_1

| PERSON_ID | LDTS |
| --- | --- |
| 45 | 2022-03-03 15:41:05.685 |
| 72 | 2022-03-03 15:42:08.203 |
| 15 | 2022-06-08 21:57:07.909 |
| 36 | 2022-06-28 21:58:43.558 |

TABLE_2

| PERSON_ID | LDTS | CURRENCY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 34 | 2022-03-03 15:00:21.814 | US |
| 28 | 2022-03-03 15:02:05.963 | CA |
| 52 | 2022-03-03 15:02:05.963 | US |
| 10 | 2022-06-08 14:40:13.762 | US |
| 11 | 2022-06-08 14:40:13.762 | CA |
| 19 | 2022-06-14 16:10:19.005 | US |

I am trying to join these tables and order by timestamp in order to get a result such as

| PERSON_ID | TABLE_1.LDTS | TABLE_2.LDTS | CURRENCY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 34 | NULL | 2022-03-03 15:00:21.814 | US |
| 28 | NULL | 2022-03-03 15:02:05.963 | CA |
| 52 | NULL | 2022-03-03 15:02:05.963 | US |
| 45 | 2022-03-03 15:41:05.685 | NULL | NULL |
| 72 | 2022-03-03 15:42:08.203 | NULL | NULL |
| 10 | NULL | 2022-06-08 14:40:13.762 | US |
| 11 | NULL | 2022-06-08 14:40:13.762 | CA |
| 15 | 2022-06-08 21:57:07.909 | NULL | NULL |
| 19 | NULL | 2022-06-14 16:10:19.005 | US |
| 36 | 2022-06-28 21:58:43.558 | NULL | NULL |

Would this just be a left join on LDTS? I am not sure how to get the resulting table such that the timestamps are ordered in this way and the columns that are not shared contain nulls if their values are not in the other table. When I try to do a full outer join, it looks like rows are duplicated for LDTS and LDTS becomes a singular column while the values for the other columns are all null. Thanks!

Comment: This looks more like cross join as there is no matching person_id.

Comment: Wouldn't a cross join result in some sort of pairing? Would it give the nulls in the positions that I am trying to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the rows where the key in the other table is null reciprocally could be handled as a set-based issue:

```
select T1.PERSON_ID, T1.LDTS as T1_LDTS, T2.LDTS as T2_LDTS, CURRENCY  from TABLE_1 T1 left join TABLE_2 T2 on T1.LDTS = T2.LDTS
union
select T2.PERSON_ID, T1.LDTS as T1_LDTS, T2.LDTS as T2_LDTS, CURRENCY from TABLE_2 T2 left join TABLE_1 T1 on T1.LDTS = T2.LDTS
order by nvl(T1_LDTS, T2_LDTS)
;
```

In response to the question in the comments, if TABLE_2 does not have a PERSON_ID column, then simply specify that it's null:

```
select T1.PERSON_ID, T1.LDTS as T1_LDTS, T2.LDTS as T2_LDTS, CURRENCY  from TABLE_1 T1 left join TABLE_2 T2 on T1.LDTS = T2.LDTS
union
select NULL as PERSON_ID, T1.LDTS as T1_LDTS, T2.LDTS as T2_LDTS, CURRENCY from TABLE_2 T2 left join TABLE_1 T1 on T1.LDTS = T2.LDTS
order by nvl(T1_LDTS, T2_LDTS)
;
```

Comment: If TABLE_2 didn't have a PERSON_ID column would this still work, such that the columns for TABLE_1 are (PERSON_ID, LDTS) and the columns for TABLE_2 are (LDTS, CURRENCY) ? Would the sql just exclude ```TS.PERSON_ID``` in the second select statement?

Comment: If TABLE_2 doesn't have a PERSON_ID then you would just specify `NULL as PERSON_ID` in that part of the select for the union.

Comment: Would that also be similar for selecting CURRENCY in the first select from TABLE_1 since that table doesn't contain CURRENCY?

Comment: In the case of CURRENCY, the SQL will attempt to get it from TABLE_2. If there's an exact match on the timestamp or if the row is coming from TABLE_2 in the union it will get it from there. If the row is coming from TABLE_1 and there's no exact match on the timestamp it will get the value from the join, which will be NULL. As far as PERSON_ID, it's a bit of a moving target here. Does TABLE_2 have a PERSON_ID column?

Answer (score 0):

Another one - similar to @Greg -

```
with cte(person_id, ldts) as
 (select person_id,ldts from table_1
 union all
 select person_id,ldts from table_2)
select t3.person_id, t1.ldts, t2.ldts, t2.currency from
 cte t3 left join table_1 t1
 on t3.person_id = t1.person_id
left join table_2 t2
 on t3.person_id = t2.person_id
order by t3.ldts;
```

| PERSON_ID | LDTS | LDTS | CURRENCY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 34 | NULL | 2022-03-03 15:00:21.814 | US |
| 28 | NULL | 2022-03-03 15:02:05.963 | CA |
| 52 | NULL | 2022-03-03 15:02:05.963 | US |
| 45 | 2022-03-03 15:41:05.685 | NULL | NULL |
| 72 | 2022-03-03 15:42:08.203 | NULL | NULL |
| 10 | NULL | 2022-06-08 14:40:13.762 | US |
| 11 | NULL | 2022-06-08 14:40:13.762 | CA |
| 15 | 2022-06-08 21:57:07.909 | NULL | NULL |
| 19 | NULL | 2022-06-14 16:10:19.005 | US |
| 36 | 2022-06-28 21:58:43.558 | NULL | NULL |

Answer (score 0):

Or were you trying to do something like this

```
SELECT COALESCE(T1.PERSON_ID,T2.PERSON_ID), 
COALESCE(T1.LDTS,T2.LDTS) AS T1_T2_LDTS, 
CURRENCY 
    FROM TABLE_1 AS T1 
    FULL OUTER JOIN TABLE_2 AS T2
        ON T1.PERSON_ID = T2.PERSON_ID
        ORDER BY T1_T2_LDTS;
```

IF you really wanted in the format you posted, you can also do this

```
SELECT COALESCE(T1.PERSON_ID,T2.PERSON_ID), 
    T1.LDTS,T2.LDTS , 
    CURRENCY 
        FROM TABLE_1 AS T1 
        FULL OUTER JOIN TABLE_2 AS T2
            ON T1.PERSON_ID = T2.PERSON_ID
            ORDER BY COALESCE(T1.LDTS,T2.LDTS);
```